# Переменная не отображает текст

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где тут ошибка, почему переменная mystring не отображается?

```
function myFunc()
{
    return "Vadim";
}

String.prototype.myName() = myFunc();
mystring = "my name ".myName();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String.prototype.myName()
```

По факту это является вызовом `myName()`, которой к тому моменту еще нет. А вот это

```
= myFunc();
```

Присваивает левой части операции **результат выполнения** `myFunc()`, т.е. строку, поэтому бессмысленно пытаться вызвать эту строку как функцию в следующем выражении.

Если чуть-чуть подредактировать одну строчку, то все будет работать:

```
String.prototype.myName = myFunc;
```

Другое дело, что не надо патчить нативные объекты.
p.s. Частица "не" с глаголами слитно не пишется.